# Proving a vector expression.

Tags: vectors

I have a problem in one of my exercises. 
The expression is **A**,**B** are vectors.

|| is a symbol for length.

I need to determine if the expression |**A**+**B**|>|**A**| + |**B**| is right or wrong.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Check the triangle inequality in your text or online to see what is it and why it is called triangle inequality.
Drawing some graphs will also help you see the answer.